# How can I rewrite an entire directory excluding 1 subdirectory in htaccess?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

How can I rewrite the entire "engineering" directory to a new URL save for the "engineering/tour" subdirectory which should remain?

I currently have this which redirects the entire directory:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/engineering(.*) /academics/academic-areas/engineering-technology-and-environmental-studies/
```

Answer (score 0):

if you can use mod_rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?engineering
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?engineering/tour
RewriteRule . /academics/academic-areas/engineering-technology-and-environmental-studies/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use just add negative lookahead in your rule:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/engineering((?!tour).*) /academics/academic-areas/engineering-technology-and-environmental-studies/
```